# Connect to Remote host (FTP) using VS Code Live Share

Tags: visual-studio-code, ftp, filezilla, vscode-liveshare

We are working on a website and all files are on a Linux Cpanel host. I can easily connect to the host using FileZilla, Open the files which need to be edited in VS Code and work on them with other members using Live Share and then upload back to server with FileZilla. However, this is a pain! Only the host computer can open files, save them and upload them back to server. I also tried [SFTP extension by liximomo](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liximomo.sftp) to shorten the process but as it opens the files on server and they're not downloaded to computer like FileZilla, others can't see the files.

Is there a way to open the whole remote host (using FTP) on VS Code so everyone (via Live Share) can browse files, open, edit and upload them without need to ask the host to do so?